# unexpected difference between types results

Tags: c++, floating-point, int, precision

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

string number = "159";
float valueFloat = 0;
int valueInt = 0;
int main()
{
    for(int i = number.length()-1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        valueInt += (number[i]-48) * pow(10,i);
        valueFloat += (number[i]-48) * pow(10,i);
    }
    cout<<"Int value: "<<valueInt<<endl;
    cout<<"Float value: "<<valueFloat<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Int value: 950
Float value: 951
```

Why this code is returning different values? Why Int type is wrong there?

Comment: http://cpp.sh/7nlp

Comment: Because `pow` calculates a floating point result, that gets truncated when converting to int.

Comment: Next time say why you would expect the output to be different, I will upvote though, since you are still new here.

Comment: "Why Int type is wrong there?" -- It *never is wrong*. The program does *exactly* what you told it to do. If results are not what you expected, you didn't tell it what you thought you did. (Finding faults in compilers or standard libraries is *highly* unlikely, especially for beginners.) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is not consistent behaviour. It may return the right number even in `int` on some platforms. The problem is in  `pow(10,i)` this function return a `float` number and when add it to other `int` (or `char`) it would return a another `float` number. Then you are adding the whole number to an `int` variable which means that a casting from `float` to `int` is necessary. The number that you are getting in `float` may be `951` or `950.99999` (or something similar). if `950.99999`  is casted to `int` it would be `950`. That explains the results.

if you want to stick to an `int` variable for some reason (which does not seem exist) you should do something like that instead:

```
for(int i = number.length()-1; i >=0; i--)
{
    float p_float=pow(10,i);
    int p_int=static_cast<int>(p_float);
    p_int=(p_int-p_float)>.5f?p_int+1:p_int;
    valueInt += (number[i]-48) * p_int;
    valueFloat += (number[i]-48) * p_float;
}
```

Or as *@Mats Petersson* mentioned you can just use `std::lround`:

```
for(int i = number.length()-1; i >=0; i--)
{
    valueInt += (number[i]-48) * std::lround(pow(10,i));
    valueFloat += (number[i]-48) * pow(10,i);
}
```

Comment: Or use `round` - but I would simply "accumulate" an integer multiplier by starting on 1 and multiplying by 10 each time - most likely faster [even for floating point values] than calling `pow`.

Comment: Is not round return a float? However, the other solution is better but the case may not be alwayse about pow

Comment: You may meant to mention std::lround. Yes it is better.

Comment: `round` returns a float rounded to the nearest integer. So, assuming `pow` actually returns something reasonably close to the correct value, it would give the right value as an integer result [and it should for any value valid as both integer and float, once you get out of the `float` range it may go wrong].

Answer (score 1):

Even though I couldn't re-generate what you see with gcc 4.9.2, I added some printfs in the loop, like this:

```
printf("%d\n", pow(10, i));
printf("%f\n", pow(10, i));
```

and got:

```
gsamaras@pythagoras:~$ g++ -Wall pc.cpp 
pc.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
pc.cpp:14:27: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__gnu_cxx::__promote_2<int, int, double, double>::__type {aka double}’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%d\n", pow(10, i));
                           ^
gsamaras@pythagoras:~$ ./a.out 
1076101120
100.000000
1076101120
10.000000
1076101120
1.000000
Int value: 951
Float value: 951
```

I suspect that you see this behavior because of the [pow()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/), which has this signature (closest to `int`):

> float pow (float base, float exponent);

As a result, `pow()` returns a `float` which is then been converted to `int`, which may result in loss of some accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `pow` calculates the value not as an integer value (perhaps `pow(x, y)` is calculated `exp(ln(x)*y)` - but it doesn't HAVE to be exactly that way), but as a floating point value, and it will have a small rounding error. This may be "below" or "above" the correct value, and since conversion from `float` to `int` is by truncation, `950.999996` gets converted to `950` rather than `951`. You can solve that, in this case, by rounding the result of `pow` to the nearest rather than truncating [assuming the result is less than +/-0.5 off from the infinitely precise value].

The way floating point values are calculated is ALWAYS with a degree of precision. Integer calculation is always exact to the least integer value of the calculation itself, but of courwse, the rules of C and C++ is that if one side is floating point, the calculation is performed in floating point.

I would completely eliminate the use of (often troublesome) `pow` from the code. A much better way, both for calculating the correct value and speed, is to use a multiplier value that is updated each loop iteration. Something like this:

```
int imult = 1;
float fmult = 1.0f;
for(int i = number.length()-1; i >=0; i--)
{
    valueInt += (number[i]-48) * imult;
    imult *= 10;
    valueFloat += (number[i]-48) * fmult;
    fmult *= 10.0f;
}
```

[I'm showing both integer and float multiplier, not strictly required, you'd get just as good an answer using `imult` in the second loop - but it becomes a floating point value either way, so I thought I'd show both variants]

For the valid range of `int` and valid range of `float`, this should give a more accurate result. Of course, integer values in `float` are restricted to 23 bits before they start getting chopped because of lack of precision available in floating point format. So any value above around 8.3 million will be missing the least significant bit.